# Can't Stop ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm scraping hundreds of urls, each with a leaderboard of data I want, and the only difference between each url string is a 'platform','region', and lastly, the page number. There are only a few platforms and regions, but the page numbers change each day and I don't know how many there are. So that's the first function, I'm just creating lists of urls to be requested in parallel.

If I use page=1, then the result will contain 'table_rows > 0' in the last function. But around page=500, the requested url still pings back but very slowly and then it will show an error message, no leaderboard found, the last function will show 'table_rows == 0', etc. The problem is I need to get through the very last page and I want to do this quickly, hence the threadpoolexecutor - but I can't cancel all the threads or processes or whatever once PAGE_LIMIT is tripped. I threw the executor.shutdown(cancel_futures=True) just to kind of show what I'm looking for. If nobody can help me I'll miserably remove the parallelization and I'll scrape slowly, sadly, one url at a time...

Thanks

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas
import requests

PLATFORM = ['xbl', 'psn', 'atvi', 'battlenet']
REGION = ['us', 'ca']
PAGE_LIMIT = True
def leaderboardLister():
    global REGION
    global PLATFORM
    list_url = []
    for region in REGION:
        for platform in PLATFORM:
            for i in range(1,750):
                list_url.append('https://cod.tracker.gg/warzone/leaderboards/battle-royale/' + platform + '/KdRatio?country=' + region + '&page=' + str(i))
                
            leaderboardExecutor(list_url,30)
            
def leaderboardExecutor(urls,threads):
    global PAGE_LIMIT
    global INTERNET
    if len(urls) > 0:                       
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
            while True:
                if PAGE_LIMIT == False:
                    executor.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)

            while INTERNET == False:
                try:
                    print('bad internet')
                    requests.get("http://google.com")
                    INTERNET = True
                except:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('waited')
            
            executor.map(scrapeLeaderboardPage, urls)
    
    
def scrapeLeaderboardPage(url):
    global PAGE_LIMIT
    checkInternet()
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,features = 'lxml')
        table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
        if len(table_rows) == 0:
            PAGE_LIMIT = False 
            print(url)
        else:
            pass
        print('success')
        

    except:
        INTERNET = False

leaderboardLister()
```

Comment: Hello! I was wondering why are you using threads instead of asynchronous requests?

Comment: To be honest it's less code and it worked on a different project

Comment: Actually it;s designed for the same thing you want to do. Plus I think it'll take much less code (and issues) than Thread based code.